# Get all users first visit date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a list of dates and ip addresses, of the users first view. Take this list of 2 days (there will be more ip's in the actual data):

```
"day"           "ip"
"2014-07-01"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-01"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-01"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-02"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-02"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-02"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-02"    "173.8.118.153"
"2014-07-02"    "173.8.118.153"
```

I want to return `2014-07-01` for this user's first day. What can I do to get a list of all the users first days?

The query I have here works, but I know it is not correct because if I change `order by` from `asc` to `desc` and vise versa, I still get the same day. Basically this is telling me that it is getting the first day that it finds for this ip, and who knows the data may be backwards in the database for some users. What can I do to guarantee that I am getting their first visit date?

```
select date(viewed) as day, inet_ntoa(ip) as user_ip
from ad_views
where ad_id = 3058440
and viewed > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
group by user_ip order by day;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `MIN()` of date:

```
select MIN(date(viewed)) as day, inet_ntoa(ip) as user_ip
from ad_views
where ad_id = 3058440
group by user_ip;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select min(date_col) from table_name
```

[This](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784) documentation could prove useful to your search

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already grouping, take the `min` of the `viewed`

```
select date(min(viewed)) as day, inet_ntoa(ip) as user_ip
from ad_views
where ad_id = 3058440
and viewed > date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
group by user_ip order by day;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT day, ip
FROM MyTable t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t2
    ON (t1.ip = t2.ip AND t1.day <= t2.day)
```